# How to rollback all database changes after all tests finished in Laravel 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unit-testing

I am trying to find a way to rollback all database (mysql) changes (transactions) once after my tests finished. Not after each test method but after all of them done. I read that `DatabaseTransactions` trait is used for this kind of approach but it rolls db transactions back after each test method. Operation going like:

```
Run Test1 -> Perform DB transactions -> Rollback -> Run Test2 ... -> Run LastTest
```

But what I need:

```
Run Test1 -> Perform DB transactions -> Run Test2 ..... -> Run LastTest -> Rollback
```

PS: I know I should use different database for testing and can use `RefreshDatabase` trait for it. But in my case I can't use different database. Please don't ask why)

Comment: But in my case I can't use different database. Please don't ask why >> WHY?

Comment: Maybe you should run the tests with a mock to prevent actual changes? Otherwise its up to you to track what you made and how to undo it

Comment: Your tests should be independant i.e. you should be able to run a single test without having it rely on other tests having provided with a specific database state. If you are doing this for the sake of speeding the tests up (because rolling back after each test is indeed slower) then you can consider running mysqldump on your database before the tests and then restoring afterwards (this can be automated in a script or using phpunit hooks). Of course this will make it slower if you indeed need to run any test on its own as you'd be backing up and restoring the entire db

Comment: @Techno Because database is too big and it not written with migrations. We already have development database that is independent from production. Whenever some changes (Changes like adding indexes, columns or changing column type or smth else) made on production database they are also updating development one. But if we will need 3rd one we will need to do same changes on 3 different places.

Comment: @apokryfos I am writing tests to test my APIs and all of them are depends from each other. User can not perform 2cn API before performing 1st one. And on each API I am updating some customer data in database and using it for upcoming APIs. Then what is the best approach for my case?

Comment: AFAIK, you don't need migrations to copy/paste a DB. Just use mysqldump to create copy and import it ;)

Comment: It doesn't matter by what it is written after each change in database we will need to copy/paste DB. Migrations are just easier way to do thats why I pointed it out

Comment: I don't see why you would need to sync everything, as this is for testing and nothing else, but if you insist on using a screwdriver like a hammer, please do. I don't know why the nail is not going in.

Comment: It's bad practice to design your tests like this. Tests are meant to test an individual feature or unit and need to be standalone. If your 2nd test depends on the first you should change that and instead set up the 2nd test to have the necessary state in the database to run without any dependencies or leverage mocking better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone who might get confused like me in the future I highly recommend to use Mocking for Unit testing to fake both your database and 3rd party APIs. After making some more research I have found that Unit tests should be independent from each other. They shouldn't affect database and 3rd party APIs shouldn't got called while testing.

For more understanding `mocking` in laravel please check out the links:

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/mocking

https://ralphjsmit.com/laravel-mock-dependencies

https://matthewdaly.co.uk/blog/2018/02/25/unit-testing-your-laravel-controllers